# Flutter riverpod listen to ChangeNotifierProvider

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

In this code i have a simple `riverpod` provider which that should connect and listen to events. here connect to pusher work fine and i can receive data from that and printing in `logcat`, but i can't listen to that in defined provider into screen

```dart
final pusherProvider= ChangeNotifierProvider<PusherController>((ref) => PusherController.instance
  ..setEventName('my-event')
  ..setChannelName('my-channel')
  ..initPusher()
  ..connectPusher());
```

in this screen `ref.watch(pusherProvider)` doesn't work

screen class:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final pusher = ref.watch(pusherProvider).eventStream;
    debugPrint('received!!!!');
```

`PusherController` class:

```dart
class PusherController extends ChangeNotifier{
  static final PusherController _pusherController = PusherController._();

  PusherController._();

  static PusherController get instance => _pusherController;

  late PusherClient pusher;
  late Channel channel;
  final StreamController<String> _eventData = StreamController<String>.broadcast();

  Sink get _inEventData => _eventData.sink;

  Stream get eventStream => _eventData.stream;
  String channelName = '';
  String prevChannelName = '';
  String eventName = '';

  PusherController initPusher() {
    PusherOptions options = PusherOptions(
      cluster: "xxxxxxxxxx",
    );
    pusher = PusherClient("xxxxxxxxx", options, autoConnect: true, enableLogging: true);
    return this;
  }

  PusherController setChannelName(String name) {
    channelName = name;
    return this;
    //print("channelName: ${channelName}");
  }

  PusherController setEventName(String name) {
    eventName = name;
    return this;
    //print("eventName: ${eventName}");
  }

  PusherController subscribePusher() {
    channel = pusher.subscribe(channelName);
    pusher.onConnectionStateChange((state) {
      debugPrint("previousState: ${state!.previousState}, currentState: ${state.currentState}");
    });

    pusher.onConnectionError((error) {
      debugPrint("error: ${error!.message}");
    });

    //Bind to listen for events called and sent to channel
    channel.bind(eventName, (PusherEvent? event) {
      debugPrint("xxxxxxxxx From pusher xxxxxxxxx");
      _inEventData.add(event!.data);

      prevChannelName = eventName;
    });

    notifyListeners();
    return this;
  }

  PusherController connectPusher() {
    pusher.connect();
    return this;
  }

  void disconnectPusher() async {
    await channel.unbind(eventName);
    await pusher.disconnect();
  }
}
```